# Trying to enable 32 bit architeture and suport for Vulkan API

Tags: drivers, apt, package-management, vulkan, lutris

I'm trying to install some games in Ubuntu, specifically leagueoflegends, so I'm running this following command to add kisak-mesa PPA, enable 32 bit architecture, update and upgrade my system, install support for 32-bit games and install the support for Vulkan API:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa && sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386
```

But every time I get this error:

```
mesa-vulkan-drivers is already the newest version (22.1.0~kisak2~f).
mesa-vulkan-drivers set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libllvm14:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 : Depends: libllvm14:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can someone helpe me? I can't find a way to install libllvm14:i386

I'm using a Lenovo IdeaPadS145 i7.

Comment: That command is a whopper. Each time you see `&&` it's a different command. Break them up and run them sequentially. Then post the output of each if there are problems.

Comment: Also read: https://askubuntu.com/q/223237